# How to change all div heights if one's height changes

Tags: css, reactjs, height

I have multiple Components which has Show More button when user press Show more the component's height increase from above. I want its height to be increased from the bottom.

The idea that came into my mind is to change all component's height when someone press Show More but that still won't work because the Details that will appear on Show more varies from component to component.

```
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    background: #fff7f7;
    transition: all .2s;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2rem;

    &ShowMore {
        background: none;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }


    &Details {
        padding: 2rem;
    }


}
```

Here is my React Component

```
 <div className={classes.Tour}>
            <span className={classes.TourClose} onClick={props.close}>X</span>
            <img className={classes.TourImg} 
                src={props.photo} 
                alt={props.name + `'s Photo`}/>
            <div className={classes.TourDetails}>
            <h2>{props.name}</h2>
            <h2>{props.city}</h2>
            <button className={classes.TourShowMore} onClick={props.show}>Show More..</button>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is how it looks normally

[image: Normal]

This is how it looks when someone clicks "Show More"

[image: Show More]

Comment: In this scenario have a fixed height for you card views and when you press show more use vertical scroll to read the content , then you don't need to adjust the height of sibling cards .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of **flexbox**. Making the container of your elements `display: flex` and adding the property `align-items: flex-start`, you can be sure that they'll always be aligned at the top. Then you can show/hide the extra content with `max-height` or something like that.

This is a quick example: https://codepen.io/giumagnani/pen/ROPWZV